# How can I power 7 IL151 5mm Clear White LED leds for a sculpture in a series circuit?

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, series

I am in the midst of planning a sculpture. The sculpture will require 7 IL151 5mm LEDs with a forward voltage of 3-3.5v . I have NO experience in electronics and I've been looking around and people have stated that a series circuit would be best for most LED projects. Now since the type of circuit I'm using would require a voltage equal to the voltage of all the LEDs, I would need a power supply of 21-24.5v (if I'm correct). Now how exactly should/could I power these? I don't think I can exactly power these would an obscene amount of batteries. I was wondering if I could use a DC power supply but how could I do it if it were possible. I would really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Can you add few details on with regard to the LED's you are planning to use. Vendors like Samsung now proved LED strip, that can be powered by a LED power converter. Check this company too Light board Tec. Batteries would mean that they will need to be changed but location will be flexible. If you use AC/DC then Sculpture will restricted to AC source.

Comment: im planning on using microtivity IL151 5mm Clear White LEDs. the LEDs will be incorporated on the inside of the statue to light up certain parts of it so i dont think a LED strip would work would it?

Comment: You want a constant current power supply rated for the forward current of the LEDs. What current do they require?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fu13uk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One thing that can be tried is 3 strips in parallel. First and second strip will have 2 LEDs and series resistors. Third strip can have three LEDs and series resistor. Then a 12 V supply would be sufficient. Sizing of resistors to be made accordingly.